# ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

Iam developing a nodejs application using a open source project.When iam running the server on the port 8000 there is an error as follows `500: Internal Error. Details: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to WINDOWS:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.123.31:1433`

My database setting file is here

```
exports.dbConfig = {
    user: "sa",
    password: "",
    server: "WINDOWS",
    database: "SampleDb",
    port: 1433
};

exports.webPort = 8000;

exports.httpMsgsFormat = "HTML";
```

But here my sql 2014 configuration is like this and i dont know what the error is.Can anyone tell me what to do and iam implementing this project[Link here](http://www.techcbt.com/Post/342/Node-js-basic-programming-tutorials-videos/REST-service-GET-POST-PUT-DELETE-CRUD-using-pure-node-js)
[image]

Comment: Is the server running on the locat machine?

Comment: Yes running on my windows machine

Comment: take a look at connectionstrings.com -- you probably want to use one of the local methods listed there.  From your screen shot you have a named pipe not a port.